Implement react-dropdown-tree-select library with both radio select and multiselect for the children
I'd like to know how to use this package to implement radio button selection for the data with no children. And all the children that populate as tree within will be multiselect.
EG: A user can select only Ahmedabad or Pune or Bangalore (which has children). So on selectio  of Bangalore we show the tree of colleges under Bangalore, BMS and IITB and Christ are all in checkbox. So the value from the select dropdown would be BMS, IITB and Christ all checked. If ahmedabad is selected, bangalore or pune cant be selected.
const data = [
      {
          label: 'Ahmedabad ',
          value: 'Ahmedabad ',
      },
      {
          label: 'Pune',
          value: 'Pune',
      },
      {
          label: 'Bangalore',
          value: 'Bangalore',
          children: [
              {
                  label: 'BMS College of Engineering',
                  value: 'BMS',
              },
              {
                  label: 'IIT B',
                  value: 'IITB',
              },
              {
                  label: 'Christ University',
                  value: 'Christ',
              },
          ],
      },
  ]

How to achieve this with library?
I either get all multiselect with the children or all readioselect including the children.
I want radio select for the parent values and children values should be multiselect
